# SQL alter one column to equal the value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column1 that currently matches everything in another column2 in that same table.  I now need the column1 to automatically update when I add a new row and fill in column2.  This is in SQL.

I was thinking

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table
alter column column1 as column2
```

might work, but it appears not.

Is it possible to do this with something along the lines of an alter statement (ie. without a trigger)?

Comment: Which database system?  SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, when I said SQL I didn't mean MySQL. Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to automatically update Column2 whenever Column1 changes:

```
--My SQL Server isn't up to par, there's probably a better way to do this
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
ON Table
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE Table
    SET Column2 = Column1
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM Inserted)
```

You can also make Column2 a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE Table
  ADD Column2 AS (Column1)
```

If you *always* want the two to be in sync, I'd suggest just removing your existing column and added in a new computed column with the same name.

A third way would be to create a VIEW that simply exposes Column1 twice:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
  SELECT Column1, Column1 as Column2 FROM Table
```

Comment: My column _currently_ matches another column.  I do not wish to add a new column, I wish to alter my current column to a different behavior.

Comment: If column2 is always to be equal to the current value of column1, then you should make it a computed column as Mike suggests. Otherwise, use Mike's first suggestion to create a trigger to set it to column1's value when new rows are added.

Comment: I was hoping to make it computer field, but if this is impossible without creating a new column, I can just add the trigger.  If no one can provide a way to do this through something like an alter statement then I will mark this as my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @user912447 - Unfortunately, you cannot `ALTER` a column to make it computed.  You have to drop it first, then re-add it.